# Processing OLAP cube using SQL agent and impersonation information

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, olap, olap-cube

Yesterday I made some changes to an existing cube in SSAS. I added a new fact table to the `Data Source View`, which I linked to the appropriate dimension tables.

I then proceeded by opening up the `mycube.cube [Design]` tab and the section `Cube Structure`. From there I added a new measure group to the cube corresponding to the newly added fact table. I verified that the new fact table was implemented in the cube designer "scheme" and that the keys were correctly set.

I then saved the cube, waiting for the sql agent to process the cube during the night (it is a rather extensive cube, so I avoid processing it during office hours).

This morning I see that the OLAP cube has been processed, and that the sql agent's `View history` does not entail any errors or warnings.

However, the cube does not have the newly added measurement group. I made the same steps on a test server earlier, and that worked without any trouble.

The only difference I can see is the impersonation information in the Data Source. My questions are therefore:

> If I make changes as a user in SSAS without deploying the cube from within SSAS, and I am not the user specified under Use a specific Windows user name and password under the Impersonation Information tab in the Data Source, will the changes not be made by the SQL agent?
>
> Do I need to be the user which is stated as the Owner of the SQL agent task?

Regards,

Cenderze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to make sure the edits you made to your cube are processed into the Job steps.
For this, edit the Job and make sure the steps are modified considering your late edit.

Then to make sure a job is executed as a user particularly you may have to setup a Proxy account into the Job.
This Proxy account needs the rights to read sources and to write into the Analysis Server's target.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, my script which updates the cube in the SQL agent processes the whole cube. I don't use seperate steps in that sense. I'll check into Proxy accounts. So, basically, if I set it up as my own user in the data source impersonation information then I'd be able to run it? That is how I made it work on the test cube, but then I was the owner of the sql agent job as well.

Comment: If impersonation is used on your data sources, then the user that executes the Job step will also connect on data sources. Either the Job agent service account has the required rights, either you have to use a proxy account, either you have to specify sql user in your data sources.

Comment: As it is now, the impersonation information user in the Data Source in SSAS is a user, which has admin rights. It is the same user that is the Owner of the SQL agent. When I edit the step which contains the script that processes the cube, it is Run as "SQL Server Agent Service Account".